# Interface property inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I may not be explaining this well, as I am not familiar with the vocabulary, but I have a base level interface, `IMyStuff`, that is inherited in a chain multiple times.

```
interface IOnceRemoved 
{
    IMyStuff MyStuff{get;set;}
}

interface ITwiceRemoved : IOnceRemoved
{
    ...
}

interface ITarget : ITwiceRemoved
{
    ...
}

public void MyMethod(ITarget target)
{
    ...
}
```

I have an object of the `IMyStuff` type. Is there a way to wrap this interface so `MyMethod` will accept it as an `ITarget`?

Comment: All I have is an object of the ```IMyStuff``` type and need to call ```MyMethod``` with it.

Comment: Sorry, I read wrong the last sentence. Either `IMyStuff : ITarget` or you need to create an `ITarget` instance

Answer (score 0):

As Camilo already suggested, you need a wrapper like

```
class MyStuffAsTargetWrapper : ITarget
{
    public MyStuffAsTargetWrapper(IMyStuff myStuff)
    {
        MyStuff = myStuff
    }
    public IMyStuff MyStuff{ get; set; }
}
```

and then call MyMethod(MyStuffAsTargetWrapper(myStuff)).